# Using TestMethod from Project 1 in Project 2

Tags: c#, methods, project, projects-and-solutions

Hi i have one solution with 2 projects in it. Both have few TestMethods and i need to refere inside of one method from project 2 a method from project 1 (I'm working on VS 2015 with Selenium). Something like these:

```
namespace Project1
{
[TestClass]
public class project1Class
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void testInit()
    {
        [...]
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void methodIWantToUse()
    {
        //code of that metod
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [TestMethods...]
```

I

```
using Project1
namespace Project2
{
[TestClass]
public class project2Class
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void testInit()
    {
        [...]
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void targetMethod()
    {
        //code of that metod
        -->Here i need to use method from project1<---
        //more code of that metod
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [TestMethods...]
```

Yes i search for that, yes i add Project1 to references in Projec2, but i don't know what to do now xD Im kind of new with that type of work.

Thx for all help.

Comment: Sharing tests doesn't look like a good idea, IMHO. Try refactoring the bits you want to share into a common class and then inherit or compose with this class.

Comment: Well the method isn't `static`, so you have to initialize an instance of the class first. `new project1Class().methodIWantToUse();`
And please create classes like `CamelCase`

Comment: it returns me that error
_CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Project1.project1Class'_